# How to center inline images using Google Docs API v1 and Python

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I'm trying to center an image using Google Docs API and Python, i followed the documention which suggests to define an inline image. The image is shown in the generated document but is not in the center of the document. 
Is there any way to center the image? 
Here is my code:

```
        requests = [
    {
        'replaceAllText': {
            'containsText': {
                'text': '{{ customer.name }}',
                'matchCase': 'true'
            },
            'replaceText': context['customer'],
        }},
    {
        'insertInlineImage': {
            'location': {
                'index': 55
            },
            'uri':
                'https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/docs_64dp.png',
            'objectSize': {
                'height': {
                    'magnitude': 50,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                },
                'width': {
                    'magnitude': 50,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
risk_assessment_customer = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={}).execute()
result = service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=risk_assessment_customer['id'], body={'requests': requests}).execute()
request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=result['documentId'],
                                             mimeType='application/pdf')
```

Thank you

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to insert an inline image to the center of Document using Google Docs API.
- You have already been used Google Docs API with Google Client Library for Python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I modified your request body.

#### Modifiaction point:

- In order to align the image to the center, `updateParagraphStyle` is used.

#### Modified request body:

Please replace the request body as follows.

```
requests = [
    {
        'replaceAllText': {
            'containsText': {
                'text': '{{ customer.name }}',
                'matchCase': 'true'
            },
            'replaceText': context['customer'],
        }
    },
    {
        "insertInlineImage": {
            "location": {
                "index": 55
            },
            "uri": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/docs_64dp.png",
            "objectSize": {
                "height": {
                    "magnitude": 50,
                    "unit": "PT"
                },
                "width": {
                    "magnitude": 50,
                    "unit": "PT"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "updateParagraphStyle": {
            "range": {
                "startIndex": 55,
                "endIndex": 56
            },
            "paragraphStyle": {
                "alignment": "CENTER"
            },
            "fields": "alignment"
        }
    }
]
```

#### Reference:

- [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.